# Logical Question about Exercise 7 on p.111 in “Analysis on Manifolds” by James R. Munkres.

Tags: general-topology, limits

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

There is the following exercise on p.111 in this book:

[image]

Munkres says "$B\subset E$ because the limit cannot be defined if $\mathbf{x_0}$ is not a limit point of $S$".
Logically no problem about this sentence?

When we discuss if $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x})=0$ holds or not, I think $x_0$ must be a limit point of $S$.
So, I think we cannot discuss if $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x})=0$ holds or not when $x_0$ is an isolated point of $S$.

I think "For an isolated point $x_0$, $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x})=0$ fails to hold" is a nonsense sentence because "$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x})$" cannot be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munkres adopts the following convention:

[image]

This means that writing $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = y_0$ is an abbreviation for the following two conditions:

1. $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$.
2. $f(x) \to y_0$ as $x \to x_0$.

If one of these two conditions is not satisfied, then $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = y_0$ fails to hold. It is perhaps unusual to interpret $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = y_0$ in that sense, and it may cause confusion, but it is consistent in itself.

By the way, we *could* of course define "$f$ approaches $y_0$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$" as above *without any restriction on $x_0$*, but if $x_0$ is an isolated point, then $f$ approaches **each** $y_0$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ - simply because $x_0$ has an open neigborhood containing no other point than $x_0$ itself. This does not make much sense, and this is why Munkres says that he does not attempt to give a definition in that case.

Comment: Paul Frost, Thank you very much for your answer.